# How to extract a hashmap object from jdbc template query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to extract 2 lists/arrays of Integers from a JDBCTemplate query.
I assume retrieving a Map would be the most practical.
The query is

```
Map<Integer, Integer> availabletime = jdbctemp.query("
Select a.hour, 
    s.duration from appointment as a inner join services as s on a.service_fid=s.id 
where date=? and guru_fid=? 
    ",date,guru_fid,//mapperlogic.class);
```

I need a.hour and s.duration as key value pairs of a hashmap. I'm a bit confused regarding the row mapper logic here. Ive mapped only to objects as of now like

```
public class RoleRowMapper implements RowMapper<Role> {

@Override
public Role mapRow(ResultSet row, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
    Role role=new Role();
    role.setId(row.getLong("id"));
    role.setName(row.getString("name"));
    return role;
}
```

}
` Can someone help me with extracting query results to Maps or multiple lists??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.query() will always return list. Hence, added .get(0)

```
  public Map<Integer,Integer> getAvailableTime(Date date, Integer guru_fid) {
                return jdbctemp.query("Select a.hour, s.duration from appointment as a inner join services as s on a.service_fid=s.id where date=? and guru_fid=? ",new Object[] { date, guru_fid }, (ResultSet rs) -> {
                HashMap<Integer,Integer> results = new HashMap<>();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    results.put(rs.getInt("a.hour"), rs.getInt("s.duration"));
                }
                return results;
            }).get(0);
    
        }
```

Comment: Does this method accidentally skip the first record? Compare the number of records that the method returns and the direct select to the database returns.